# Color nodes by networkx

Tags: python-3.x, csv, networkx, topology

I am generating a network topology diagram through the data in a csv file where s0..s2 and c1..c3 are nodes of the diagram.

**network.csv:**

> source,port,destination
>
> s1,1,c3
>
> s2,1,c1
>
> s0,1,c2
>
> s1,2,s2
>
> s2,2,s0

I need to make all the source to be blue and destinations to be green.
How can I do it without overriding the source nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is a working solution:

```
import csv
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

with open('../resources/network.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    edges = {(row['source'], row['destination']) for row in reader }
print(edges) # {('s1', 'c3'), ('s1', 's2'), ('s0', 'c2'), ('s2', 's0'), ('s2', 'c1')}

G = nx.DiGraph()
source_nodes = set([edge[0] for edge in edges])
G.add_edges_from(edges)
for n in G.nodes():
    G.nodes[n]['color'] = 'b' if n in source_nodes else 'g'

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
colors = [node[1]['color'] for node in G.nodes(data=True)]
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color=colors)
plt.show()
```

We first read the csv to an edge list, which is later used for the construction of G. For well defining the colors we set each source node with blue and **the rest** of the nodes as green (i.e., all destination nodes that **also not source nodes**).

We also use `nx.draw_networkx` to get a more compact implementation for drawing the graph.

The result should be something like:

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much for the help. But sometimes I am getting one source node as green(s2). I have a program where everytime I run the main program(diff python file) I have new connections in the csv. So sometimes when I am running this code I am getting one source node green

Comment: Happy to help :) It's difficult to say why it happens without the actual code and data. Probably the edges / source_nodes are not what you think they are. Try printing them and reproduce such a scenario. Worth saying that the csv part is completely irrelevant to the drawing part, and my guess is that the problem is with reading the csv.

Comment: Now I have one more node in destination i.e. M0, can you tell me how can I give it a different color than other two nodes please?

Comment: How can I add the edge weight from the CSV from port no. ? example: S11, S21, etc on their edges?

Comment: That's another question, which I'd be happy to answer. Why changing the original question if you accepted an answer? The idea of SO is answering a question once, also for **others**. Now the answer has nothing to do with the question, as it answers the original question.

Comment: I am sorry I thought if a generate a new question  it might not be noticed by you.

Comment: It's ok, and don't worry SO has a strong community and someone will probably answer your question pretty quickly. For the first question - you control the colors with the line `G.nodes[n]['color'] = 'b' if n in source_nodes else 'g'`. Just change the logic of assigning colors to nodes.

Comment: For the second question about edge weights:
1. You should read the CSV file with: `edges = [(row['source'], row['destination'], {'w': row['port']}) for row in reader]`
2. You'll need to draw the edge labels with: `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels={(e[0], e[1]): e[2]['w'] for e in G.edges(data=True)})` before running `plt.show()`

Comment: I am getting this error for the edge weight improvement....unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: And I don't want only the port no. to be printed as weights but with the corresponding source id, like: s11, s21, s01, etc

Comment: For solving the "unhashable type: 'dict'" error - note that it's `[(row['source'], row['destination'], {'w': row['port']}) for row in reader]` and **NOT** `{(row['source'], row['destination'], {'w': row['port']}) for row in reader}` (**look at the outmost parentheses type**)

Comment: And for the second part - I'm sure you can take it from here, just concatenate the strings as you wish when creating 'edge_labels'.

Comment: can you check this one   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458259/call-dictionary-from-one-function-to-another